# How is execution resumed after a hardware breakpoint without an infinite loop?

Tags: debugging, gdb, cpu-architecture, breakpoints

**As far as I know SW-breakpoints are working as follows:**

The instruction the BP is set to gets substituted by a int/trap instruction, than the trap is handled in a trap handler, on continue the trap is replaced by the original instruction, the instruction is executed in single step mode, now the PC points to the next instruction and the original instruction is replaced again by a int/trap instruction.

**HW Breakpoints work as follows according to my understanding:**

The address of the instruction the BP is set to is written in a HW-BP Register. If the instruction is hit respectively the PC matches the address in the HW-BP Register, the CPU raises an interrupt which is also handled by a trap handler. Now if the program returns to the orignial instruction the HW BP is still active and one is caught in an infinite loop.

**How is that problem treated?**

Is the HW BP disabled before continuing and is the orignal instruction also getting executed in single step mode? Or is the original instruction executed before the trap handler is entered, so that the trap handler returns to the instruction after the original instruction? Or is there an other mechanism?

Comment: Are you asking about any specific ISA, or across CPU architectures in general that have HW-BP registers like x86's DR0..7?  (Not all do; I know ARM doesn't have a hardware equivalent of x86's single-step TF, so Linux `ptrace` doesn't support single-stepping there; debuggers have to do it themselves.)

Comment: My first guess was that the OS would use the Trap Flag to run 1 instruction, then set the breakpoint again. Didn't know about the Resume Flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of the Intel 64 and IA-32 ("x64/x86") architectures, this is the task of the **Resume Flag (RF)**, bit 16 in EFLAGS. (Other processor architectures that support hardware breakpoints probably have a similar mechanism.)

See section 18.3.1.1 in the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3B](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/pentium4/sb/253669.pdf):

> Because the debug exception for an instruction breakpoint is generated before the instruction is executed, if the instruction breakpoint is not removed by the exception handler; the processor will detect the instruction breakpoint again when the instruction is restarted and generate another debug exception. **To prevent looping on an instruction breakpoint, the Intel 64 and IA-32 architectures provide the RF flag (resume flag) in the EFLAGS register** (see Section 2.3, “System Flags and Fields in the EFLAGS Register,” in the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3A). **When the RF flag is set, the processor ignores instruction breakpoints.**
>
> [...]
>
> **The RF Flag is cleared at the start of the instruction after the check for code breakpoint**, CS limit violation and FP exceptions.
>
> [...]
>
> **If the RF flag in the EFLAGS image is set when the processor returns from the exception handler, it is copied into the RF flag in the EFLAGS register by IRETD/IRETQ or a task switch that causes the return. The processor then ignores instruction breakpoints for the duration of the next instruction.** (Note that the POPF, POPFD, and IRET instructions do not transfer the RF image into the EFLAGS register.) Setting the RF flag does not prevent other types of debug-exception conditions (such as, I/O or data breakpoints) from being detected, nor does it prevent non-debug exceptions from being generated.

(Emphasis mine.)

So, the debugger will set RF before returning from the exception handler so that instruction breakpoints are "muted" for one instruction, after which the flag is automatically cleared by the processor.

Note that this is not a concern in the case of data breakpoints because these will fire *after* the instruction that triggered the read/write operation.

---

Recommendation: I find [the slides of "Intermediate x86 Part 4" by Xeno Kovah](https://opensecuritytraining.info/IntermediateX86_files/IntermediateIntelx86-Part4.ppt.pdf) to be helpful in understanding these things. He talks about various topics there but starts with debugging. This information in particular can be found on slides 12-13:

[image: slide 12]
[image: slide 13]

<sub>Image credit: Xeno Kovah, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>